# How to query copyright claims on your youtube video via youtube api

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am uploading videos in which on background I play music sometimes. This music gets copyright claims from time to time. I will be notified about it when I upload my video and youtube will process it. Video will have section with copyright claims: **song played, owner and times it played in my video**. **I would like to query this specific copyright info** from API to effectively remove claimed music from videos. Video list endpoint does not seem to have this information.

Example of a video: ID: **6JHpax2o6gM**

[Claim screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7OiB.png)

Comment: as SO user johnh10 stated in their answer, such info is not included, but, I would like to give a change. Can you share some `videoId` that has this particularity? if so, please [edit] your question and add this details.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave, sure, just edited my post you can check an example of the claim at the bottom of my post. Thx for the /try/ :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API does not include copyright info.

Comment: I assume, if API does not provide this functionality, then the only way to get it is to run custom scrapper?

Comment: @Adam that seems the only option. I tried, but not results. sorry.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave, Thank you for trying. Will try selenium option, or something else.